# spring boot properties yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-kafka

I run spring boot and kafka with auto configuration(via annotattions only) and having props defined in .yaml file, ie:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: someserver:9999
    consumer:
      group-id: mygroup
....

 @KafkaListener()
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
....
  }
```

And it works fine, spring maps i.e. the field group-id properly.

But when i try configure kafka manually(with ConsumerFactory and ConsumerConfig) using the same yaml file then i run into problem.
In class ConsumerConfig kafka properties are named with . in name, not _ i.e.:

```
public static final String GROUP_ID_CONFIG = "group.id";
```

So I cant just load them into map and pass the map to ConsumerFactory because keys are with _ not .

I dont want to do it as ugly as shown in example provided by spring kafka team, when they map props from yaml into config class and then manually assign props in the map to be passed to factory:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private String brokerAddress;

    private String topic;

    private String fooTopic;

    public String getBrokerAddress() {
        return this.brokerAddress;
    }

.....

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.configProperties.getBrokerAddress());
    .....

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the dotted properties in the yml file, you need to do it like boot does for arbitrary properties that are not directly supported as boot properties:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        group.id: foo
```

i.e. populate a `Properties` property.

The reason boot provides first class support for some properties is so that IDE editors can provide content-assist, which is not possible with arbitrary properties.